# Eclipse Android не видит support-library-v4

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

У меня есть старый проект, собирать его нужно в Eclipse, ибо Android studio его не переваривает при импорте проекта. Суть такова, что библиотек много, их я подключил, но основная проблема в том, что в 4 библиотеках из 10 есть Support-library-v4, и что самое удивительное в каждой библиотеке она разная, а именно разные итерации. Я удалил лишние копии и добавил 1 самую актуальную в основной проект, но при всё этом даже после чисты проекта и сборки по новой библиотеки не видят support library, только после того, как я её добавлю в проект. Как сделать так, чтобы была лишь одна её копия, которую бы видели все библиотеки и основной проект. Спасибо

Comment: Библиотеки как проекты подключали импортировав в ворк спейс?

Comment: @Suvitruf ДА, именно так и делал, я в курсе проблемы, если не импортить в workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создать проект `my-support-library`, в котором будет только либа
   Support-library-v4.
2. Сделать проект библиотекой.
3. Подключить эту библиотеку во всех библиотеках, где нужен  Support-library.

Comment: Попробую и отпишусь, надеюсь получится. И раз уж такое дело, то подскажите, как добавить jar архив с либой, пожалуста)

Comment: Сработало, спасибо. Теперь опять старая беда с R файлом в проектах. Его не видит Eclipse. К сожалению я уже года полтора на Eclipse не делал проекты под андрюху

Comment: @BORSHEVIK R файл автоматически генерируется. Если его нету, значит где-то в xml ошибка, скорей всего.